# How to handle js.liquid and css.liquid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify, liquid

I'm developing a web using Liquid template like Shopify.

In liquid template of Shopify , there are some files: file1.js.liquid, file2.css.liquid, i don't know how to transform these file to normal file file1.js, file2.css

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

You donot need to transform these files. Shopify will automatically generate the .js or .css file from your .css.liquid or .js.liquid file.

Simply load your css file like this

`{{ 'file2.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}`

or

`{{ 'file1.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}`

Comment: Thanks for your comments. But i would like to know how to implement these filter asset_url, stylesheet_tag . Because it is not provided in standard liquid.

Comment: You can read about these url filters here. https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/filters/url-filters

Shopify may have added more features to liquid language to make everything work.

Comment: The `asset_url` filter prepends your filename with the appropriate CDN link to the asset folder of your theme.  The `_tag` filters turn those links into pre-formatted HTML tags.  If you're in a non-Shopify environment, you'll just need to code those pieces in manually